# How would I parse this string?

Tags: linux, grep

I have the string "http://example.com http://example2.com" how would I grep them into two different variables?

I'm very new to Linux.
Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of variables? Shell? Perl? Ruby? Java? PHP?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` loop

```
str="http://example.com http://example2.com"
for word in $str
do
    echo $word
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Spontaneously, I wouldn't use `grep`, but `read`:

```
EXAMPLE="http://example.com http://example2.com"
read URL1 URL2 <<<"$EXAMPLE"
```

The `<<<` syntax assumes that you're using Bash, however. Otherwise, you'd have to do it like this:

```
read URL1 URL2 <<EOF
$EXAMPLE
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are all great, but there are many ways to skin this problem, so here's another. :-) Since your string is space-separated, and your shell's default separator (`IFS`) includes space, you can take advantage of this:

```sh
mystr="http://example.com http://example2.com"
set -- $mystr
foo=$1    # http://example.com
bar=$2    # http://example2.com
```

(The `--` after `set` isn't strictly required in this instance, but it prevents some stupid things from happening in case your string happened to start with a dash for some reason.)

Answer (score 2):

As an altnerative answer to my previous one, you can also use the following syntax, which should be available in all standard shells:

```
EXAMPLE="http://example.com http://example2.com"
URL1="${EXAMPLE%% *}"
URL2="${EXAMPLE#* }"
```

You can see the Bash/Dash manpage for further information on how they work.

Comment: Yes, technically this works, but it's probably easier and more readable to rely on `IFS` tokenisation, as used in all the other answers. :-) (And if the delimiter isn't a space, it's easy enough to adjust `IFS` accordingly.)

Comment: I agree, but they all have their uses. Might as well present it. :) I would argue that it's a bit ugly to mutate `IFS` just to do some local operation, however.

Comment: It's not so ugly if you're using `local` (supported by bash and dash) to set it, within a function.